# How to use List<Hashtable> from c#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

How to store and retrieve values from List in C#? I can store values like this

```
List<Hashtable> mList=new List<Hashtable>();
Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
ht.Add(1, "One");
ht.Add(2, "Two");
ht.Add(3, "Three");
ht.Add(4, "Four");
mList.Add(ht);
```

How to set these values to base adapter textview in C#?

Comment: I don't know about Xamarin textview but it looks very strange to put an old-style hashtable in a `List<>`. Are you sure you need this?

Comment: thanks buddy.Yes i need and tell me the old style also. I want to store multiple values using key

Answer (score 1):

> How to set these values to base adapter textview in C#?

I assume that your base adapter means the `BaseAdapter` for a `ListView`, then you can create a adapter inherit from `BaseAdapter` for example like this:

```
public class MainAdapter : BaseAdapter<Hashtable>
{
    private List<Hashtable> items;
    private Activity context;

    public MainAdapter(Activity context, List<Hashtable> items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;
        this.items = items;
    }

    public override Hashtable this[int position]
    {
        get
        {
            return items[position];
        }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get
        {
            return items.Count;
        }
    }

    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        View view = convertView;
        if (view == null)
            view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, null);
        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Android.Resource.Id.Text1).Text = items[position].ToString();
        return view;
    }
}
```

and use the `List<HashTable>` for your adapter like this:

```
public class MainActivity : ListActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);

        List<Hashtable> mList = new List<Hashtable>();
        Hashtable ht = new Hashtable();
        ht.Put(1, "One");
        ht.Put(2, "Two");
        ht.Put(3, "Three");
        ht.Put(4, "Four");
        mList.Add(ht);

        ListAdapter = new MainAdapter(this, mList);
    }
}
```

But I doubt this is really what you need. You have only one item in `List<>` and this item has one `Hashtable` which contains four key-pair value. Is it possible that you need a key-pair value to be shown on each item of `ListView` instead of showing four key-pair values in one item?

I do agree with @Henk Holterman, it is very strange to put an old-style hashtable in a `List<>`, if you want to use `List<>` to store multiple string values with key, you can simply code like this:

```
List<string> mList = new List<string>();
mList.Add("One");
mList.Add("Two");
mList.Add("Three");
mList.Add("Four");
```

`List<>` itself allocates a index for each item, for example, if you want to find the index of string item "Three", you can code like this:

```
var index = mList.IndexOf("Three");
```

Since the first item in `List<>` will match the index of 0, here the index of item "Three" will be 2.

Of course I'm not saying it is not allowed to store a `Hashtable` into a `List<>`, but usually when we want to define a Key for each item, one method is to create a class model, for example:

```
public class MyListModel
{
    public int Key { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

And now you can create a `List<>` for this model:

```
List<MyListModel> mList = new List<MyListModel>();
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
    mList.Add(new MyListModel { Key = i, Content = "item " + i });
}
```

The advantage to use a data model for `ListView` is that if your each `ListView` item has for example more than one `TextView`, each is for displaying different information, then you can simply add those properties in this class model.

For more information of building a `ListView` in Xamarin.Android, you can refer to [ListViews and Adapters](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/user_interface/working_with_listviews_and_adapters/).